# How do I search for apps on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, search, bug

Prior to iOS 14 it was possible, from any of the home pages, to flick down and search for an app. For example, with a simple workflow consisting of

> flick, "p", "c"

to find PCalc.
But since installing iOS 14 this capability seems to have been lost. When I take those steps now I'm unhelpfully offered things like the website of the "Porsche Club of America" or the Presbyterian Church (sites I've never visited and have no interest in) or a stock ticket for PCA (whatever that is, I don't even have stocks or use the stocks app). And if I type out "pcalc" and hit Search I get an App Store link to a version I don't want, and useless web links about the app:

[image]

In order to find an app now it seems I need to run through all of my home screen pages in order to get to something called the App Library:

> page, page, page, page, [view I don't need], "p", "c"

Is this now the only way to find apps?

How do I search for apps in iOS 14? Is the App Library now the only way to do this?

Comment: Seems unlikely, BUT...  check this setting.   Settings > Siri & Search - scroll down to an app you're not finding, like PCalc.  Select that.  Make sure that the options are enabled to show it on the home screen suggestions, and in search, etc.   These should always be enabled by default, but since you're seeing odd behavior... double check and make sure.

Comment: Also to add, your question "Is the App Library the only way to do this", no it should not be.   I can search for any app that way - Apollo, Spotify, even Calculator.   As you mentioned, swipe down, start typing the name of the app.   Shows up right at the top of the page.   I open most apps this way.

Comment: @Charlie74 _Settings > Siri & Search_ is enabled, and search doesn't work for _any_ app, not just PCalc. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in 14.0, now repaired in 14.0.1. If you are experiencing this, first see if it goes away with an updated to a version if iOS 14 greater than 14.0.

Answer (score 0):

PCalc is my top result for a search for ‘pc’ on iOS 14.

If you've only just updated to iOS 14, your device will likely still be indexing. This is probably the same issue as macOS where Spotlight search is very wrong right after an OS upgrade.

Comment: Ah — _indexing_. I'll report back after a few days and see if that's what's up. How long ago did you install (as of writing I'm still < 25 hrs)?

Comment: @orome Starting from Beta 1 in June, I remember search being wrong. It was definitely for a while on both macOS/iOS betas because I thought it was wrong for longer than usual after an upgrade. I think it was about a week until search seemed good again.

Comment: Is indexing one of those things that only really happens while charging?

Comment: @orome Yes, charging, and in my experience inactive i.e. not running an app like Sleep Cycle

Comment: Still nothing; not a single installed app shows up when I search. An update can't be intended to render my iPhone basically useless for days, can it?

Comment: Still nothing. Unless for almost a week.

Comment: More than a week and still — *nothing*.

Answer (score -2):

If you go to the right on the Homescreen, there you can also find all your apps and you can also search for them.

Comment: This answer is missing a lot of info.  You can look at [answer] for important tips.