# Workout sync from Watch to iPhone is unreliable since iOS 14 update

Tags: data-synchronization, apple-watch, bug, activity.app, ios

Since updating to iOS 14, about <strike>20%</strike> **50%** of my workouts fail to sync from my Watch to my iPhone. I've restarted both Watch and iPhone, several times. Quit and relaunched the Activity app in iOS. All to no avail.

The information from missing workouts is also not present in Health. So basically Watch now no longer can be used for its primary function.

It's so bad, that I even get nonsense like this:

[image: Bug indicating 9 stand hours but showing only 6]

How do I restore the missing workouts and get sync working again, or is this [another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/401418/4395) iOS 14 bug?

Comment: Are these the same devices that had bad data injected or the health database was under stress to clean itself? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402092/apple-health-draining-battery-following-ios-14-update

Comment: @bmike: Same device, but the conclusion was that it was an app that was just too busy. As soon as I disconnected Welltory from Health, the problem went away.

Comment: It’s official, two backups are needed to fully clean the issues. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211865 one for the watch to the phone and one for the phone.

Comment: @bmike This is a scam to get me to upgrade my iPhone. I'm not doing this twice. It kills at least a day. So my choices are: buy my new iPhone now, leave Apple for Google at last (since the Apple II), start using pencil and paper.

Comment: Yeah - I would hate this procedure if I didn’t have two caching servers so I save most of my data to a local mac in my local network and make iCloud backups and iCloud restores pleasant since most of it happens at fast speeds. I lost an hour and half today, but my GPS issue is fixed. We’ll see if all the health and activity data comes back from iCloud - the phone and watch were basically functional after 90 minutes.

Comment: The hokey-pokey seems to have fixed all my issues.

Comment: @bmike It takes me half a day to get 2fa working again.

Comment: Allegedly this was fixed in 14.3/7.2 but the issue has reappeared. It seems to be associated with reboots. After restarting the phone for example, it takes several cycles of reboots of phone and watch (probably in order to achieve the magical sequencing of reboots) before things start syncing again. [What's lost appears preeminently lost.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410107/4395)

Answer (score 3):

It’s official, Apple published an article that to me explains the update had some problems and our devices may not fix themselves. It also warns of future data loss. I got bitten by the GPS bug and was not successful in fixing it by unpairing the watch, but I will follow this sequence later today once I close my rings :-) Looking closer at noise data - that's off for me and my watch isn't unlocking my Macs anymore so I'll want to restore my iPhone and watch together (first unpairing the watch, then backing up the phone, then erasing the phone and restoring / repairing)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211865

> ***If you updated to iOS 14 and watchOS 7 and are missing Activity or Health data, learn what to do to prevent future data loss.***
>
> After updating to iOS 14.0 and watchOS 7.0, you might notice:
>
> - Your
>   workout route maps are missing in the Fitness app on iPhone for
>   previous GPS-enabled workouts from your Apple Watch.
> - The Activity,
>   Heart Rate, or other health-related apps fail to launch or load data
>   on your Apple Watch.
> - The Fitness app or Health app fail to launch or
>   load data on your iPhone.
> - The Health app or Fitness app is reporting
>   an inaccurate amount of data storage on your iPhone.
> - The Activity app
>   is reporting an inaccurate amount of data storage on your Apple Watch.
> - Your environmental sound levels data or headphone audio levels data
>   from Apple Watch is missing in the Health app on iPhone.
> - Increased
>   battery drain on your iPhone or Apple Watch.
>
> *If you experience **two or more of the above issues**, follow the steps below.*

---

Old information for context before Apple acknowledged this issue.

I had this once in the past and needed to work with Apple Support to enable a support PIN so they could see my workouts sync to the cloud and diagnose the errors. In the past, they identified something the server code could clean up and all the workouts synced within 2 days of the fix.

- They walked me through one additional quick fix you didn't mention - unpair the watch and re-pair it.

Unless this is a widespread bug, the sooner you start with support, the less likely you'll lose your workouts if that's your primary goal. For a data point, I've logged dozens of workouts since upgrading all my devices on the initial day updates were released. My account hasn't needed anything, but there was a sync error in the past that caused this precise error. *(In hindsight, every one of the workouts that synced were missing GPS data - so my failure wasn't initially evident as I didn't review ALL the data after seeing the initial parts correct.)*

They told me if I wanted to wipe and lose all activity from the watch, I could unpair it, then back up the iPhone to the cloud and then wipe the phone from Finder, then it would all download - but since I had a lot of photos, I declined that and waited out the fix for the sync error they identified based on looking at the logs on the device. The concern was the backup to the iPhone wasn't guaranteed based on the logs as that used the same sync code as the workout sync.

Comment: Ugh. I wish Apple would address fundamental tech issues (why is everything associated with sync so unreliable?) rather than new bells and whistles.

Comment: Well, dealing with "support" now. We'll see how that plays out (already disconnected twice).

Comment: I’m cleaning up the comments. I know how much of a pain this is for you (and others now that it’s confirmed a bug or bad interaction...) @orome I wish I could buy you a beverage or snack so we could commiserate. I’ve lost time I would rather have not, today to hopefully fix this on my devices...

Comment: I had the same issue - missing GPS & Hearth Data. Apple Support advised to repair Apple Watch. That didn't help, Watch even stopped to track workout at all. Next advice was Restore iPhone & Watch from backup. That helped. Issues seems to be fixed since then (2 month already). On the other hand, all my workouts prior the restoration have lost their GPS data. All of them. All gone.