# How do I force sync of my workouts from Watch to iPhone?

Tags: data-synchronization, apple-watch, bug, activity.app

Since iOS 14.0 (through at least 14.3) [syncing of workouts from watch to phone has become unreliable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/401885/4395), with occasionally workouts failing to appear on the phone. Is there a way (*without* wiping or resetting the phone) to force workouts (or a specific workout) on Watch to sync to the phone, or are workouts that fail to sync in this way permanently unavailable on the phone.

Comment: I’ll wait a week before answering “no - you have to live with sync and work with Apple Support when it fails” since maybe someone has a better answer or fix that’s not obvious. Mine were cured 100% with the update in the linked question - so I can’t reproduce this anymore.

Comment: @bmike The bug was allegedly fixed in 14.3, but wasn't. So I guess were back to the mind wipe (and another wasted morning). Does Apple use some weird faulty sync tech that's embedded deeply in their stack? Sync issues (calendar, contacts, workouts, health data, mail, etc.) seem to plague just about every product. I don't have these issues with Google at all.

Comment: No, the sync code is extremely robust (in my experience)  - we see it fail far less often than competitors at work, but no system is perfect. If your keys are corrupt or your database needs repair, it doesn’t matter how robust the code is, your data needs to get repaired or set aside, sadly. Anecdotal reports are hard to validate, only when you have thousands of people logging tickets can you tell which are less stable in my experience again.