# How do I get HR data on my Watch to my iPhone?

Tags: data-synchronization, health.app, health-kit

I have HR data that I can see on my Watch, but on my iPhone there is a gap where a chunk of that data is missing (both in the Health app and in all linked apps that get HR data from HealthKit).

How do I get my Watch to send the data to my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Like backups, Heath data should sync automatically when your watch is paired to your phone and they both can connect to wifi.

I would take the watch and phone to a different wifi and possibly reset network settings to ensure they both can join wifi. Some watches have different chips so you may need Apple support to help you determine which wifi channels both devices support.

If that doesn’t work, I would unpair the watch to force a backup and sync and then setup the watch again.

Something is amiss and these are the items I’ve seen people get stuck on and one I had to do once quite a few years back. [Is this the same hardware you needed to work on previously?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402356/5472)

Comment: Honestly I'm tired of having to do this. The devices are both on the same wifi (or as Apple has it "Wi-Fi") network, have been for ages, everything is up to date, etc. etc. There's _nothing_ out of the ordinary going on here; but it just breaks and there's zero feedback and zero UX. Just crickets. (The issue here is that I while I might take an afternoon off to fix this, most people — quite rightly — won't bother, and I lead a team that vets this stuff for the design of health apps and services. Our conclusion is that Apple's health data is not useful or reliable; just a toy.)

Comment: I agree - it’s always a pain to troubleshoot a connection when you don’t have logs or a “reconnect” button. I have gotten excellent help from Apple support all two times I ran into a different situation where health data wasn’t what I wanted or expected. They have profiles they can load to get at the engineering logs to diagnose and fix. @orome